# How would I make this loop, it stops after 2 iterations

Tags: python

I've decided to make a bot social experiment for a game I play where people can just play with bot, but I've run into a problem. I tried to make it loop but the code does not - it only goes 2 level ids then ends the run. How do I make it loop forever instead of going twice then stopping? Could it be `gd.py` or on my end?

**`imports`**:  `keep_alive`, `gd`, `time`, `random`, `os`

Comment: It's difficult to debug code that not present (except by guessing). Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it only goes twice is because you only have 2 level ids, so it goes through each one once and then it's done. If you'd like to make it go forever and just pick between those 2 level ids, use a while loop with an exit condition.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

As enzo pointed out, if the goal is to make it go forever and you have to close the program to make it stop, then you can achieve this with `while True:`, which will never be False and therefore won't end.

Comment: I think you meant "a while loop *without* an exit condition".

Comment: @enzo sorry, yes, for it to go on FOREVER there should be no exit condition, but I assumed this was a smaller part of something so it would eventually have to end, but you are right

Comment: Oh ok, no problem!

Comment: @noahhhha accept the answer and close the question if you're satisfied, people search for questions with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to know why it only iterates two times? Okay according to your code it should run only 2 times. In `for level in levelids:` you say the program to iterate through ids in `levelids = [10565740,3979721]`. So the code runs through these two elements and ends the program.

So you need to run it forever? According to your code if you want to run the code indefinitely then you need to add elements to `levelids` list indefinitely.

I feel like there is confusion with what you want to do with your code and what code does for you.